# Может ли геттер и сеттер быть статичным?

Tags: c#, классы

Можно ли задать геттер статичным,но при этом сеттер приватным/публичным?
И для чего нужны статичные геттеры и сеттеры?

Comment: Кхм, кхм. Для статических свойств. Можно.

Comment: Очевидно, для доступа к статическим свойствам

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166508/5752652 в c# также. Но это какой-то очень редкий сценарий.

Comment: Геттер или сеттер отдельно не могут быть статическими, статическим может быть только свойство целиком. А для чего статические свойства? Ну классический пример — синглтон, а также всевозможные свойства `Default`/`Current` в том числе в стандартной библиотеке